# How to setup Laravel using a shared host with sqlsrv?

Tags: php, sql-server, laravel, shared-hosting, sqlsrv

I have a project developed in Laravel and I want to upload the project to a Linux shared hosting.

In my project I have 2 connection to different database. First is mysql database that is in shared hosting and works well. Second is an sql server database that access to another server. So for that second database I use sqlsrv driver but I having problems to put this working at linux shared hosting, returns me this error:

```
SQLSTATE[HY000] Unable to connect: Adaptive Server is unavailable or does not exist (severity 9)

at PDO->__construct('dblib:host=IP:1433;dbname=DBNAME;charset=utf8', 'USER', 'PASSWORD', array(0, 2, 0, false))
```

I set the connection like this:

```
'DB2' => [
        'driver' => 'sqlsrv',
        'host' => env('DB_HOST', 'IP'),
        'port' => env('DB_PORT', '1433'),
        'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'DBNAME'),
        'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'USER'),
        'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', 'PASSWORD'),
        'charset' => 'utf8',
        'prefix' => '',
    ],
```

Before this error I have a lot of another errors because this connection, so I have to add some extensions to php and update to 7.2 version. I also add some `PHP pear packages` .

The next image show you the extensions that I add:

[image]

In my local machine I can run the project without any problem and both connection working fine.

How can I solve that?

Comment: Does your shared hosting package make an SQLServer instance available? Normally not as these have to be paid for as it is an M$ product

Comment: Hi, do you manage to get the solution?

Answer (score 0):

You should define `DB_HOST` and `DB_PORT` environment variables inside `.env` file for sqlsrv driver. Currently, it looks like the default values are used for the connection. (Default value - is the second parameter of env() function). 
P.S. Please note, if you use two different connection - variable names should be different, for example:

`.env` content:

```
...

    MYSQL_DB_HOST=0.0.0.0
    MYSQL_DB_PORT=3939
    SQLSRV_DB_HOST=0.0.0.0
    SQLSRV_DB_PORT=1433
...
```

`config/database.php` content:

```
...
    'DB' => [
            'driver' => 'mysql',
            'host' => env('MYSQL_DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
            'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3939'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'DBNAME'),
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'USER'),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', 'PASSWORD'),
            'charset' => 'utf8',
            'prefix' => '',
        ],
    'DB2' => [
            'driver' => 'sqlsrv',
            'host' => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
            'port' => env('DB_PORT', '1433'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'DBNAME'),
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'USER'),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', 'PASSWORD'),
            'charset' => 'utf8',
            'prefix' => '',
        ],
...
```

Answer (score 0):

I think first of all check your hosting server php version and try to put correct PDO driver for PHP version.

if you use a PHP Version 7.1.7 for *86 Architecture then put that .dll file.

> extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_71_ts_*86.dll

and if you use another Version of PHP then try to put a correct .dll file and also declare into php.ini file.

and restart your service and run it...

I hope it would help you...